# What is the use of '.class' in Java

Tags: java, class

Actually this is a three part question.

**1** I want know to know on what occasions do we use the keyword `class`. It is obvious that we use it to 
define a class. But what is the purpose of using `SomeClass.class` in a expression?

**2** I read on Wikipedia that it can be used instead of the expression `new SomeClass().getClass()`. But why do we need this when we already can use  `new SomeClass().getClass()` expression?

**3** And when do we need to use this `SomeClass.class` expression in a statement?

I am referring to Anonymous Inner classes and it occurred to me we can't use the `getClass()` method in a static method.

**The following answer from Stephen gives the exact unique answer for this problem.**

Comment: What do *you* think about the questions? What are *your* thoughts and reasoning? What have you read?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can u read it now I made my corrections

Comment: @NemindaPrabhashwara his point was: are you sure it's getclass() and not getClass() ?

Comment: @Stultuske yes it needs to be `getClass()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But what is the purpose of using `SomeClass.class` in a expression?

It is called a class literal; see [JLS 15.8.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2).

The purpose is to get the `Class` object that for the class denoted by `SomeClass`.  (But you already knew that ...)

> But why do we need this when we already can use `new SomeClass().getClass()` expression?

Because `new SomeClass()` creates a new instance of `SomeClass()`:

- This is unnecessary
- It may be expensive
- It may have unwanted side-effects
- It may be necessary to supply multiple arguments
- It may not even be possible; e.g. if the constructors are not accessible, or the class is `abstract`.

> And when do we need to use this `SomeClass.class` expression in a statement?

There are numerous use-cases involving reflection where you need the `Class` object for a class to do things.  Start by reading [a good tutorial on Java reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

---

> I am referring to Anonymous Inner classes

A class literal can't be used to get the `Class` of an anonymous inner class.   But `this.getClass()` will work in any instance<sup>1</sup> method of an anonymous class.

> ... it occurred to me we can't use the `getClass()` method in a static method.

Well, I guess that would be a scenario where you need a class literal.

But strictly speaking you *can* call `getClass()` in a static method.  The problem is that you can't call it on `this`, either explicitly or implicitly.

---

<sup>1 - I can't think of a convincing use-case for a static method in an anonymous class.  It would only be possible to refer to such a method outside of the anonymous class by using reflection.  So it may as well be declared as an instance method.</sup>

Comment: We can call the `getClass()` method for another different object in a static method am I right?